# Docker - "no-new-privileges"

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am having a little challenge around using the `--security-opt=no-new-privileges` flag for Docker.

I am trying to follow [this guide](https://www.smarthomebeginner.com/traefik-2-docker-tutorial/#Google_OAuth_20) to build a Docker home server, and I managed to do everything. But in order to get things running, I had to turn off said flag. As for where I enable it, the container does not create and the log shows "standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "operation not permitted"" error.

As I am getting this when directly running a container:

```
  fabrice@docker-01  ~  1  sudo docker run -ti --security-opt=no-new-privileges --name test fedora:25 bash
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "operation not permitted"
  fabrice@docker-01  ~  1 
```

I am assuming it is not an error in the guide or the docker-compose, but in my Docker installation. I am just not entirely sure how to troubleshoot it or resolve it. (I have installed Docker at the initial package selection of the Ubuntu 20.04 OS install, and added Docker Compose to the system using [this guide](https://www.smarthomebeginner.com/docker-home-media-server-2018-basic/#Add_Linux_User_to_Docker_Group).)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `su` terminal account?

#### Linux/Ubuntu

Type `su` and then enter your user password.

#### macOS

Type `su` and then enter `alpine` (default password) or your user password.

## Also, read this note

It seems that you can do `sudo -i` to become the root user using your `sudo` user password but I don't know if that's the same as the actual root command (`su`)

### Links

| URL | Answer Status | Website | Poster | Has profile on Stack Overflow? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [How to become superuser using `su`/`sudo` on Ubuntu or Linux](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/become-superuser-on-ubuntu-linux/) | N/A | Other (N/A) | Vivek Gite | No |
| [standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "operation not permitted"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61320237/standard-init-linux-go211-exec-user-process-caused-operation-not-permitted) | Answered | Stack Overflow | [Robgogo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8794014/) | Yes, linked |
| [Does anyone know a workaround for no-new-privileges blocking selinux transitions in docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44127247/does-anyone-know-a-workaround-for-no-new-privileges-blocking-selinux-transitions) | Answered | Stack Overflow | [Iotos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8051626/) | Yes, linked |
| [exec user process caused "operation not permitted" due to OPTIONS='--selinux-enabled'](https://github.com/fnproject/fn/issues/1497) | N/A | GitHub | [louwersj](https://github.com/louwersj) | No, linked GitHub |

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Sadly being root gives the same error... (did sudo -i, also tried with sudo su)

root@docker-01:~# sudo docker run -ti --security-opt=no-new-privileges --name test fedora:25 bash
standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "operation not permitted"
root@docker-01:~#

Comment: Updated post to contain more links and made it look more stylish. All credits go to the authors of them posts. Sorry that I can't help out, maybe the new posts I have linked do help you out.

Answer (score 0):

So I ran into this question looking for something else & it seems to not be answered & it seems that the syntax is just wrong.
Now, this may have been right at the time, but as of 2023-02-12 it is not.

I'm used to using it mostly in docker-compose where it looks like this

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  container:
    image: 'host/container:latest'
    container_name: container
    environment:
      PUID: 1000
      PGID: 1000
    volumes:
      - /docker/host/path:/container/path
      - /docker/log/var/log:/var/log:rw
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    restart: unless-stopped
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
```

`security_opt:` isn't a variable being set, it's an option

a quik search finds a container using it in what I would believe to be the proper formatting

```
  docker container run --name rando-doggos --rm -it \
  -p 5000:5000 \
  --user 1500:1500 \
  --security-opt no-new-privileges \
  --memory 128m \
  --cpus 0.75 \
  qualimente/rando-doggos:2018-03-20-1030
```

It's not what I would expect, having `no-new-privileges=true` but it does separate the option then calls the value as I would expect. `--security-opt no-new-privileges` instead of separating with an `=` separate with a space. What you are doing here is calling for an option `--security-opt` & then setting an option for it `no-new-privileges`. I assume if you included `=true` it would work as well, since it's a Boolean value & calling for it without a value should be setting it to on/true. But I am not going to confirm that, it's just what I believe to be happening.

I don't know if there are other problems with your container, but that should solve this problem & work properly if there are not other errors.